# UIButton setImage in UITableViewCell crashes app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

As of right now, my table loads three cells. Two of the cells' labels include the string "Test". When I search "Test" the first time, the expected cells load and the correct images, label texts and button backgrounds are displayed. Nothing overlaps. So far so good there.

However, the app immediately crashes when I cancel the search and go back and search "Test" again (as soon as I enter the last character "t").

I get this error:

```
-[UIImageView setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9128140
2014-06-19 14:12:19.982 appName[5171:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception      'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9128140'
```

I made sure the instance was the UIButton and not the UIImageView in the cell. I read on other answers to add 100 to the button tags, but nothing changed. By the way, the button tags are correct when I search. (I checked with an alert for every button click)

Below is my code for the cells.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// register cell identifier from custom cell NIB
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FriendCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Avatar settings
UIImageView *imvAvatar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 3, 45, 45)];
[imvAvatar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnAvatar2.png"]];
imvAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = imvAvatar.frame.size.height/2;
imvAvatar.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

// Befriend Button settings
UIButton *btnBefriend = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(281, 14, 36, 22)];
[btnBefriend addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBefriendPressed:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    friend = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
} else {
    friend = [arrFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
}

// Collect friend info
NSString *user_id = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:0];    // user id
NSString *username = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:1];   // username
NSString *fName = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:2];      // first name
NSString *lName = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:3];      // last name
NSString *full_name = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:4];  // full name
UIImage *picture = (UIImage *)[friend objectAtIndex:5];      // picture (img)
NSString *type = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:6];       // type
NSString *arrIndex = (NSString *)[friend objectAtIndex:7];   // arrFriends index

// configure cell
if (!cell) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // set width depending on device orientation
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, tableView.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height);

    // Name settings
    UILabel *lblName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRectMake(60, 3, 215, 45))];
    [lblName setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];

    // Update name, status, picture, befriend button
    lblName.text = full_name;                           // full name
    imvAvatar.image = picture;                          // picture (img)
    if ([type isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [btnBefriend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBefriend.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        [btnBefriend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBefriended.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    // Cell subviews
    imvAvatar.tag = 1;
    lblName.tag = 2;
    btnBefriend.tag = [arrIndex intValue];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imvAvatar];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:lblName];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnBefriend];
    cell.clipsToBounds = YES;    
}
else {
    // Make sure images, buttons and texts don't overlap

    // avatar
    UIImageView *imvAvatar = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    imvAvatar.image = picture;
    // name
    UILabel *lblName = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    lblName.text = full_name;
    // befriendbutton
    UIButton *btnBefriend = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:[arrIndex intValue]];
    if ([type isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [btnBefriend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBefriend.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else {
        [btnBefriend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnBefriended.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is on this line:

```
UIButton *btnBefriend = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:[arrIndex intValue]];
```

You're expecting a `UIButton` but the actual view being returned is a `UIImageView`. So it's possible that `[arrIndex intValue]` has the same tag as an image view that's also a subview of the cell's content view.

Comment: Thanks. I figured my way around that making these changes.
btnBefriend.tag = [arrIndex intValue]+100;
UIButton *btnBefriend = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:[arrIndex intValue]+100];

Now when I search for the first cell that doesn't include "Test", that button tag is 1 when it should be 0. FYI: The "Test" cells are the last 2 out of the 3 cells.